# Roman and Arabic numbers string array sorting in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

My array contains list of the Arabic and roman numbers as string. I would like to sort them by the order of Roman numbers ascending first then follows the Arabic numbers in ascending order.
I write the code as below,

```js
var myarray = ["i", "ii", "iii", "xv", "x", "1", "2", "3", "5", "601", "vi", "vii", "88", "99", "201", "101", "xix", "125", "iv", "vi", "v", "xiv", "58"]
myarray.sort(function (a, b) {
  try {
    if (Number(a) != null)
      a = Number(a);
    if (Number(b) != null)
      b = Number(b);
  } catch (e) {}
  if (a > b) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (b > a) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a == b) {
    return a.position - b.position;
  }
});
console.log(myarray);
```

But the results are like,
Results: `ii,iii,xv,x,1,2,3,5,v,vi,vii,vi,iv,xix,xiv,58,88,99,101,125,201,601,i`
If I have not convert the string to numbers, 
Results: `1,101,125,2,201,3,5,58,601,88,99,i,ii,iii,iv,v,vi,vi,vii,x,xiv,xix,xv`
My expect result should be
Results: `i,ii,iii,iv,v,vi,vi,vii,x,xiv,xv,xix,1, 2, 3,5,58,88,99,101,125,201,601`

Comment: You have to sort both parallel and than merge the arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple things here:

- You don't need a try / catch block. Just leave it.
- Checking the parsed number for null won't give you the expected result. You need to check for NaN.
- Either parse both values to a number or none. Otherwise you can't compare properly.
- Usually numbers will be returned before strings. To avoid this behaviour you need to invert the result value by multiplicating with -1, if one value is a number and one is a string.

Here is the working version of the sort method:

```js
var myarray = ["i", "ii", "iii", "xv", "x", "1", "2", "3", "5", "601", "vi", "vii", "88", "99", "201", "101", "xix", "125", "iv", "vi", "v", "xiv", "58"]
myarray.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (!isNaN(Number(a)) && !isNaN(Number(b))) {
    a = Number(a);
    b = Number(b);
  }
  var result;
  if (a > b) {
    result = 1;
  }
  if (b > a) {
    result = -1;
  }
  if (a == b) {
    result = a.position - b.position;
  }
  if (isNaN(Number(a)) !== isNaN(Number(b))) {
    result = result * -1;
  }
  return result;
});
console.log(myarray);
```